# Correct parenthesis

Tags: c, parsing, recursion

I came across this problem :

"It gives a string of round brackets. This string represents a parenthesis that is not necessarily correct. You have available the next move : you can change an open bracket '(' into a close brachet ')' or vice versa. You have to calculate the minimum number of moves needed to make the parenthesis to be correct."

e.g.

)())

answer : 1

First of all, I think that it would be useful to use parsing, but the program doesn't seem to work right.

```
void X() {
    if(first=='(') {
        firt=fgetc(fi);
        X();
        if(first!=')')
            er++;
        first=fgetc(fi);
    }
    else {
        ..
    }
}
```

What would be an idea of beginning?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to propose an algorithm. First the pseudo code:

```
For each input character C:
   If C is '(' then 
      increment counter
   else if counter is 0 then    // The closing paren has no matching opening
      increment moves           // so we "flip" it and counting as the opening
      increment counter
   else
      decrement counter        // This closing paren is balanced
   end if
end For
// Now the counter is containing the number of unbalanced opening parentheses,
// so we add half of this number to moves, as half of them have to be balanced
moves = moves + counter / 2

return moves
```

Now in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void) {

    char input[] = "((((";
    int len = strlen(input);
    int i;
    int moves = 0;
    int count = 0;

    for (i=0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (input[i] == '(')
        {
            count ++;
        }
        else
        {
            if (count == 0)
            {
                count ++;
                moves ++;
            }
            else
            {
                count --;
            }
        }
    }

    moves += count / 2;
    printf("Moves: %d\n", moves);
    return 0;
}
```

You are invited to test it with different inputs [here](https://ideone.com/jXPbc3), prove it's correctness or disprove with a counterexample input :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way (in Pascal). Fixes the actual string and shows before and after.

```
function FixBrackets(s: string): Integer;
var
  LeftToProcess, OpenCount: Integer;
  I: Integer;
begin
  writeln('in:', S);
  Result := 0;
  LeftToProcess := length(s);
  OpenCount := 0;
  for I := 1 to LeftToProcess do begin
    case S[I] of
    '(' :
      if LeftToProcess <= OpenCount then begin
        // we must close all
          S[I] := ')';
          inc(Result);
      end else
        inc(OpenCount);
    ')' :
      if OpenCount = 0 then begin
        // we have no open pars to close, so this has to be a new open
        S[I] := '(';
        inc(Result);
        inc(OpenCount);
      end else
        dec(OpenCount);
    end;
    dec(LeftToProcess);
  end;
  writeln('out:', s);
end;
```

Comment: Hm.. Can you give a link to ideone wit full code, for those who have forgot Pascal completely? :)

Comment: or for those who never know it

Comment: What programming language would you like it in? ;)

Comment: Well, the question tagged `c`.. Anyway, I just can't parse the part it is producing the "correct" string when there are some unbalanced `(` left after  the end of input (this part just discouraged me from returning the corrected string in my answer, as I haven't seen an elegant way to do that).

Comment: Those two `S[I] :=` statements are assignments. Open brackets are converted to Close brackets if there are currently so many Open brackets that the remaining ones must be Close ones. Conversely, Close brackets are converted to Open brackets if there are currently no Open brackets (reading left to right and keeping track of how many unclosed brackets we have).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer in C++:

```
template<class T>
int count_changes(T begin, T end) {
    int offset = 0;
    int changes = 0;
    for (auto it = begin; it != end; ++it) {
        if (*it == '(') ++offset;
        else --offset;

        if (offset < 0) {
            offset = 1;
            changes++;
        }
    }

    return changes + ((offset + 1) / 2);
}

int main() {
    std::string parens { "))(()" };

    cout << parens << " : " << count_changes(parens.begin(), parens.end()) << endl;
}
```